# How to import all documents from one DB to another DB in marklogic?

Tags: marklogic, marklogic-9, mlcp

how can i export all documents from one DB to another DB in marklogic?
I mean from one environment to another environment. Like SIT to UAT.
Which is the best way to do it?

Comment: Besides MLCP, there is Backup/Restore and DB Replication, and Flexible Replication.

Answer (score 2):

MarkLogic Content Pump supports three commands: import, export, and copy. Sounds like you want to copy. You specify the connection information for the input and output sides, along with any filters you might want to constrain which documents to copy. You'll also want to decide whether to copy permissions, collections, and a few other options (probably yes).

The [Copying Content Between Databases](https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/mlcp/copy) section of the MLCP Guide has basic steps, examples, and a full command line option reference.

Comment: We tried this but we're facing some privilege issue. So, is there any other method to export documents?

Comment: @DeepanChelliah can you elaborate on that? If you need more space, you can edit your question to add details there..

Comment: @grtjn basically we need to move all the documents from SIT environment to UAT environment. We can't use mlcp copy method as there was some user privilege issue. So is there any other way we can do it?

Comment: going to need more detail on the user privilege issue.

Comment: @DaveCassel : Hi sir, please help me for https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58541604/how-to-connect-github-desktop-with-cpanel