# How to connect github desktop with cpanel

Tags: linux, git, github, repository, cpanel

I have a repository on cpanel and connected with my local PC.
When I do changes in any of the file I go to cmd, type git commit -a , git push ......it asks my cpanel password and I enter and successfully push the changes to cpanel and my website changes are appeared

But I want to commit changes from GitHub Desktop to cpanel repository instead of typing commands via cmd.

Do I need to create an online github account and create a repository with same name there and connect with that?

Also I have enabled ssh-key but still the Github Desktop says Authentication error when I try to push to origin. In my origin the path is : ssh://user@mydomain.com/myfolderpath

[image: please refer the image below]

Answer (score 0):

If you are relatively new to GitHub and git, it would be best to just create the repository on GitHub and set up the ssh (or just do url cloning if the repo is not private) for it using the cmd. Use this ssh on Cpanel to be able to push to github and have cpanel update based on the github.

Comment: Can the commits be directly done from Github Desktop to my cpanel repository? Or does first the commit needs to be done to my github.com online account repository then from there the cpanel will pull the updates from the online account